# Sticky Service Management

Tags: android, service, sticky

I've got a Sticky Service (returns `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand`) which executes some code in an `AsyncTask`, but I'm having some problems with how and when to start, bind, stop, unbind.  I only want the service around whilst the parent activity is alive, I don't want it hanging around in the background when the app has been closed, but I need the service to survive an orientation change.  I currently don't need the service to be active for the entire duration of the activity being active, so I call stopSelf() after the main work is done in my `AsyncTask` in the `Service` and then start the `Service` again when needed.  Sometimes I'll need to interrupt the work the service is doing, cancel the `AsyncTask` and start again with different data. The problem is that no matter what I do - I can't seem to get it solid throughout all the different possible scenarios. Can anyone have a look through and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My `Service` is :

```
public class ChordCalculatorService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private AsyncTask<SearchData, SearchStatusData, List<Item>> currentTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {}

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * Class for clients to access. Because we know this service always runs in
     * the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ChordCalculatorService getService() {
            return ChordCalculatorService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public SearchData getSearchData() {
        return searchData;
    }        

    public void startWork() {
        if (currentTask != null && currentTask.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING) {
            currentTask.cancel(true);
        }
        if(searchData != null) {
            Worker task = new Worker();
            currentTask = task.execute(new SearchData[] { searchData });
        } else {
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(ERROR, "No search data set");
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }


    class Worker extends AsyncTask<SearchData, SearchStatusData, List<Item>> {
        // ... code ...

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> result) {
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(COMPLETE, new StatusData(Status.STATUS_FINISHED, result));
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have the `Service` being started when my custom `View` is created:

```
public class MyCustomView extends BasicFretBoardView  {

    private ServiceConnection conn;
    private MyService myService;
    private boolean isServiceStarted;
    private boolean isServiceBound;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        startService();
    }

    public void startService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
        conn = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                myService = ((LocalBinder) service).getService();
                myService.registerHandler(serviceHandler);
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                myService = null;
            }
        };

        // Explicitly start the service. Don't use BIND_AUTO_CREATE, since it
        // causes an implicit service stop when the last binder is removed.

        getContext().startService(serviceIntent);
        getContext().bindService(serviceIntent, conn, 0);
        isServiceStarted = true;
        isServiceBound = true;
    }

    public void stopService() {
        if (isServiceStarted) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
            getContext().stopService(serviceIntent);
            isServiceStarted = false;
        }
        unBindService();
    }


    public void unBindService() {
        if(isServiceBound) {
            getContext().unbindService(conn);
            isServiceBound = false;
        }
    }

    // gets called based on some user interaction
    private void startServiceWork() {
        if(!isServiceStarted) {
            startService();
        } else {
            myService.cancelCalcalation();
        }
        myService.setData(data);
        myService.startWork();
    } 
}
```

and stopping the service is handled in the `Activity`:

```
public class CustomChordActivity extends Activity {

    // ... code ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(isFinishing()) {
            chordsView.stopService();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        chordsView.unBindService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, why are you binding and explicitly starting the service? I thought you either bind to the service or explicitly connect to it. I'm not sure you need getContext().startService(serviceIntent);.

Comment: ** replacement for incorrect deleted comment **  Because I'm not using BIND_AUTO_CREATE on the bind, I think I need to explicitly start the service too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want your task to run on demand, maybe an IntentService would be a more suitable option. When you need work to be done, (startServiceWork()), you just start the service and that kicks off your AsyncTask. The service will then finish after the task has finished.

Now, regarding orientation changes, you would have to implement a Broadcast Receiver whose intent filter is "android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED". (I assume that you want the service to do work when the orientation changes) Place the Broadcast Receiver, within your activity/main ui thread. This will in effect make the hosting process of your Broadcast Receiver to be the main application process making it safer to start the service from within the Broadcast Receiver.